# Handling AppEngine Memcache Timeouts

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

`com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException: The API call memcache.Get() took too long to respond and was cancelled.`

What is the best way of handling Memcache errors like this? I assumed that memcache calls (as opposed to datastore calls) would just return null if they fail for some reason, since null results are always possible when cached items are dropped from the cache.

### I'm considering wrapping the memcache calls with my own methods to catch the exceptions and return null.  Any better ideas?

Edit: I now see that you can set error handlers.  The LogAndContinueErrorHandler is supposed to be the default but it's unclear exactly what's set/being used.  This would seem to be way to go though.

---

Edit: Here's the full stack trace:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException: The API call memcache.Get() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$3.createDeadlineException(ApiProxyImpl.java:318)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:44)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:51)
    at mikelike.account.Account.getPrivateBoardsFromCache(Account.java:1110)
    at org.apache.jsp.inc.dialogs.pin_005fdialog_jsp._jspService(pin_005fdialog_jsp.java:77)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.inc.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(ResourceFileServlet.java:342)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(ResourceFileServlet.java:281)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.doGet(ResourceFileServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at mikelike.common.MikeLikeServletFilter.doFilter(MikeLikeServletFilter.java:191)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

---

Edit: Here are the headers:

```
Host: www.mikelike.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.mikelike.com/pin/PiAILvNi4yA3c/no-description
Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: Shift_JIS,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: bookmarklet=mikelike; __utma=144575401.2134744684.1335291737.1336151354.1336236818.8; __utmb=144575401.263.10.1336236818; __utmc=144575401; __utmz=144575401.1336236818.8.7.utmcsr=pinterest.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/nagakubo/watch-later/; fbm_247980821960554=base_domain=.mikelike.com; fbsr_247980821960554=bCuJN2JJUzK9RpAzxnurnPTaWLLYIk3MAnBrjDn0_WE.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiIyLkFRQ1JJeldBYWUyY1FHUGcuMzYwMC4xMzM2MjQ4MDAwLjEtMTI1ODY2OTgzN3xLWEd4MVVNYS12T0k2RGxWaW90NVppRndWZ1kiLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzMzYyNDQxODMsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMjU4NjY5ODM3In0
X-Zoo: app-id=mikelikecom,domain=mikelike.com,host=www.mikelike.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
X-Google-Apps-Metadata: domain=mikelike.com,host=www.mikelike.com
X-AppEngine-Country: JP
X-AppEngine-Region: 13
X-AppEngine-City: fuchu
X-AppEngine-CityLatLong: 35.668973,139.477661
X-AppEngine-Default-Namespace: mikelike.com
```

---

Edit: Here's the full log entry.

```
2012-05-12 18:37:24.317 /ml/scripts/set_bookmarklet_cookie/?pin_service=mikelike&_=1336873018270 500 25355ms 2kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.5 Safari/534.55.3

99.226.111.36 - - [12/May/2012:18:37:24 -0700] "GET /ml/scripts/set_bookmarklet_cookie/?pin_service=mikelike&_=1336873018270 HTTP/1.1" 500 2793 "http://pinterest.com/pin/126593439495821330/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.5 Safari/534.55.3" "www.mikelike.com" ms=25356 cpu_ms=19232 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.635415 instance=00c61b117c5f07e0509d55c89da88f028311b8

W 2012-05-12 18:37:23.996

/ml/scripts/set_bookmarklet_cookie/
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApiDeadlineExceededException: The API call memcache.Get() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$3.createDeadlineException(ApiProxyImpl.java:318)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:44)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:51)
    at mikelike.account.Account.getAccountFromCache(Account.java:1053)
    at mikelike.common.MikeLikeServletFilter.getUserAccount(MikeLikeServletFilter.java:209)
    at mikelike.common.MikeLikeServletFilter.doFilter(MikeLikeServletFilter.java:165)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: can you show us the full error stacktrace?

Comment: Can you also include the request log header?

Comment: Added request headers.  Took a while before the error re-occurred but had another instance of it today.

Comment: I was referring to the log header in the admin console: showing number of ms the request took to execute, and if it was loading request or not

Answer (score 0):

Is this error occuring on dev server ? If so, keep in mind that memcache memory use will grow over time (if you don't explicitly clear items..) as internal memcache api is not properly managed on dev server.

Comment: No, this is only in production.